# UITextInput dictationRecordingDidEnd was called, but insertDictationResultPlaceholder didn't

Tags: iphone, uitextinput, dictation

I'm implementing a custom text view for rich text edit,it implements `UITextInput` protocol, when using dictation, I found that `-dictationRecordingDidEnd` was called ,but `-insertDictationResultPlaceholder` never get called, so it won't show the place holder for dictation, any idea?